# 2 Trusted Domains One Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-2010, active-directory

As a quick followup to a prior question - I now have two standalone domains in a two way trust relationship - but not Transitive. I am able to add users from either domain to shares on the other. Sweet. What I would now like to do, the final thing, is to allow users from Domain B to use Exchange on Domain A using login credentials from Domain B - if possible.

I just tried to create a User Mailbox in Exchange 2010 on Domain A and all the options when browsing for users only show Domain A and its OU's. I see now way to locate Domain B.

Any thoughts or options??

I wa sthinking about creating the users in Domain A but I am missing the link on how I could associate these acocunts with their Domain B accounts...I am only talking about 3 users from Domain B at this time.

As usual - any help or pointers is appreciated ;)

Comment: I have Domain B's domain setup in Exchange on Domain A. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved on my own, but forgot to come back here. Eventually using the full Domain B credentials worked on the users PC to connect back to Exchange. Not sure if it was a rebbot or just giving in 10 minutes that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you created your trust you created an external trust and you need to create a Forest Trust.  You also need to have forestprep and domainprep run in the other forest/domain without installing exchange.